# Boss RC-300 seamless change to new phrase memory for song medleys

Tags: looping, looper-pedals

So far I've just been using the Boss RC-300 looper for single songs.

But now I want to use it for medleys of songs.  Problem is when I switch phrase memories using either the Loop FX switch or an external control switch like the Boss FS-6, the phrase memory switches but the second phrase memory doesn't start when the playing loop ends.

I want some way to cue the next phrase memory loop end just like I can cue the next track on loop end in a given phrase memory.

Any way of doing this seamlessly or am I just going to have to tap dance and hope for the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to set the tracks to play in series with each song in a different track.